# What tools are available on my mac for performing QA for web applications?

Tags: tools, web-application

Like many web software shops we all have macs.
What tools are built in or easily and cheaply available for macs in performing QA?

Comment: I do not understand the question. Are you asking a list of applications for MAC specifically? This has got to be a long list considering most QA/Testing applications are available for both Mac and Windows.

Comment: My answer has 4 tools.  I don't know of any others.  Do you have a list of others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For screenshots do <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>apple</kbd>-<kbd>4</kbd>.  This save it in a `.png` format that is good for inserting into tools like Jira
2. To add text on top of screenshot snip is a free mac store download
   *"Snip is a screen-capture application that can capture the active window or custom areas. Drag to zoom in/out the screen shot; add labels, texts and handwriting contents of your choice and save it to your device or the clipboard."*
3. For either workflow or animation testing use Quicktime Screen Recording to capture a movie (`.mov`) file.   Easy access with <kbd>[apple]</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> then type `qa` and pick it.
4. For notes you can use Text Edit to create basic text documents

Comment: DB clients (MySQL; Postgres) should be available for the Mac.  Any Java-based testing tools like JMeter should run there too.  And of course bug-tracking tools like Jira and Bugzilla run inside a browser.